# LaTeX printing in ipython qtconsole when running external file

Tags: latex, ipython, qtconsole

I solved an analytic problem using sympy and saved everything in a .py file. When I run the code (which includes init_printing()) with ipython filename.py I get nice unicode output whenever I print within the file with pprint. So far so good.

When I import sympy in ipython qtconsole, I can get nice LaTeX outputs, just as stated in the documentation of [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html). But I get this nice printing only if the interactive console does the prining, i.e.:

```
Integral(sqrt(1/x), x)
```

produced a LaTeX image, while

```
pprint(Integral(sqrt(1/x), x))
```

does produce unicode output.

When running code from a file with

```
run filename.py
```

the only way I see to create output is to use pprint, i.e. I do not get the LaTeX output.

Does anyone see a solution? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to put the solution that worked for me here. Matt's answer somehow includes it: What I wanted is a call that creates the nice latex printout. The following does the job:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()

display(sympy.symbols("alpha"))
```

If this snippet is called e.g. with

```
%run "filename.py"
```

in qtconsole or ipython notebook, alpha will be displayed nicely.

Answer (score 0):

As in many case I think there is a confusion between returning an object (that trigger display hook) and displaying it. is is the same difference than

```
def funp():
    print 1
```

and

```
def funr():
    return 1
```

Both will "show" 1 if executed interactivly, but not in a script. In IPython you can see the difference with the Out[] prompt that appear or not depending of wether it is returned or displayed. I think in you case you need `from IPython.display import display_pretty`

```
In[1]: display_pretty(I)
⌠           
⎮     ___   
⎮    ╱ 1    
⎮   ╱  ─  dx
⎮ ╲╱   x    
⌡
```

or maybe `from IPython.display import display_latex`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
This means that the display hook method that is called in the qtconsole is able to do the LaTeX output, but I use a different method (pprint) in the script. 
How can I manually call the display hook method.
Btw. 
    alpha
prints LaTeX
    display_latex(alpha)
prints unicode

Comment: Simply use in the script display:

    IPython.display import display
    display(alpha) #or similar

Comment: display_something will call the display-hook-something for you. It is not always easy nor make sense to try to get the methods that the display_hook will call by yourself.